# Nodemon e NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

Estou aprendendo nodejs e gostaria de saber como adicionar o nodemon para que toda vez que salvar o projeto o mesmo atualizar minha página web.

Instalei o nodemon globalmente e coloquei ele na chamada do package.json

```
{
  "name": "meuprojeto",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.18.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "ejs": "~2.5.7",
    "express": "~4.15.5",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.5"
  }
}
```

Só que ao salvar, a minha página web nao atualiza automaticamente.

Também tentei executar o projeto diretamente com o nodemon, entrando na pasta e digitando `nodemon`.

Como faço pra configurá-lo de forma correta?

Answer (score 1):

1- instalar nodemon dev dependencies

```
npm install nodemon --save-dev
```

2-configurando start

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon seu-arquivo.js"
  },
```

3- rodando

```
npm start
```

exemplo:https://github.com/EduardoSampaio/back-end-jr-challenge/tree/eduardo_sampaio_15-11-2017

Answer (score 0):

Você instala o `nodemon` com

```
npm install --save-dev nodemon
```

ou com `yarn`

```
yarn add -D nodemon
```

No teu `package.json`, você deixa

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "nodemon teudiretorio/server.js"
},
```

Para rodar, basta digitar `npm run dev` ou `yarn dev`. Evita usar `start` com nodemon porque quando fizer alguma `build` dele e jogar num servidor externo, como `heroku`, por exemplo, esse servidor usará o `start` para iniciar tua aplicação. Como o `nodemon` foi instalado em modo de desenvolvimento, apenas, na hora de `startar` tua aplicação vai gerar erro porque essa dependência não vai ser instalada na aplicação. Basicamente, teu `package.json` ficará assim:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "nodemon teudiretorio/server.js",
  "start": "node teudiretorio/server.js"
},
```